# How to show different icons in a specs2 index page?

Tags: scala, specs2

We're generating HTML from specs and examples using Specs2 and like it a lot. The only problem is that the index page doesn't indicate which specs that have failing tests - it only contains links to the specs pages prefixed by a green "ok" icon, which is obviously misleading since it might lead the observer to think that all tests are green.

We've generated the index page using the following, as described in the [specs2 user guide](http://etorreborre.github.com/specs2/guide/org.specs2.guide.Structure.html#Create+an+index):

```
package examples

import org.specs2._
import runner.SpecificationsFinder._

/**Creates an index page for the specifications */
class index extends Specification {

  def is =
    examplesLinks("Specs")

  def examplesLinks(t: String) = specifications().foldLeft(t.title) {
    (res, cur) => res ^ see(cur)
  }
}
```

So, is there a way to show different icons (red?) for link with specs with failing tests in the index page?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a bug, which is fixed in 1.11-SNAPSHOT.